# my css a class is affecting my menu bar items but i only want it to work on my photo gallery

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="gallery">
        <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
        <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
        <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
        <a tabindex="1"><img src="images/smile.jpg"></a>
</div>

a{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  height:25%;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #333;
  -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

a img{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition-property:width, height;
  -webkit-transition-duration:300ms;
  -moz-transition-property:width, height;
  -moz-transition-duration:300ms;
  -o-transition-property:width, height;
  -o-transition-duration:300ms;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0.3;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

This is a real beginner question but I'm not that good with CSS anymore.

I want to use my css above to work only on my gallery class but right now it's affecting all  a href's on the page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
a{
...
}

a img{
...
}
```

To:

```
.gallery a{
...
}

.gallery a img{
...
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you; I knew it was going to be an easy question. I knew how to do it just completely spaced on it, thank you thank you.

Answer (score 1):

if you directly call a specific tag in css for e.g. a {  ....} it will affect all the anchor tags within the document. Hence you have to call only specific anchor tag wihin the gallery section.

for e.g. 
`.gallery a { ....}`

Then only the anchor tags within the gallery section will be affected